# FadeTo not properly working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fadeto

I have the Problem of my Little Code to not work as i want it to. i will post the code first.

```
$(function() {

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if( $( "#skillelementwithme" ).hasClass( "skillelement_collapsed" ) )
    {
        $( "#skillelementwithme" ).click(function() {
            $( "#skillelementwithme" ).toggleClass( "skillelement_active_withme", 500 );
            $( "#skillelementwithyou" ).fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    });
    }
    else if (( "#skillelementwithme" ).hasClass( "skillelement_active_withme" ))
    {
        $( "#skillelementwithme" ).click(function() {
            $( "#skillelementwithme" ).toggleClass( "skillelement_collapsed", 500 );
            $( "#skillelementwithyou" ).fadeTo( 1000 , 1 );
    });
    }
})
});
```

Now while the fadetotransparent works perfectly fine, i cant get the "skillelementwithyou" class to fadeto back to become opaque. Maybe i understood something absolutely wrong with these functions. I hope you guys can help me. Probably its just something so tiny that im gonna hate myself.

Comment: Off topic: `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function(){` are identical.

Comment: Thanks for the little hint :3 I am a beginner so every advice is helpful

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your classes do, but I think that entire block can be simplified to this: http://pastie.org/9435030. You may not even need the class toggle statement.

Comment: I'm curious, what do you see in the console (press F12 to launch developer tools within the browser)?

Comment: Thank you isherwood that solved the problem i had completely, the class toggle i need for the complete change of the first class. it now works as i thought it out! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pmX7z/

```
$(function () {
    $("#skillelementwithme").click(function () {
        $("#skillelementwithme")
            .toggleClass("skillelement_active_withme skillelement_collapsed");
        $("#skillelementwithyou").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

<sub>**Some of your mistakes:**</sub>

`$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function(){` are basically the same so you can get rid of one.

`( "#skillelementwithme" )` is an invalid selector (You're missing the jQuery object reference `$`).

Wrapping `click()` inside `if` statements. On JS parse time the `if` will be read, the portion returning `true` will give access to the containing `.click()` function, while the other (`false`) will be ignored and never accessible. Doing it the other way around (passing the `if` logic inside the `click` handler) helps to keep the event alive while checking the statements on every click event.

`.toggleClass( "skillelement_collapsed", 500 );` toggleClass does not accept a *time* argument. It's not an animation.